# Symfony2; distribute a "minimized" app

Tags: php, oop, symfony, composer-php, software-distribution

Being new to Symfony/Composer; I created a demo app following the recommended [Symfony directory structure](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_architecture.html#understanding-the-directory-structure) and ended up with 4 folders..

```
app/     The application configuration, templates and translations.
src/     The project's PHP code.
vendor/  The third-party dependencies.
web/     The web root directory.
```

Now I need to send the app to a client to integrate it as a snippet in their website (inside their existing code).. So I need just to send the web folder and not all my source files.

My question is; in Symfony is there any way I send them only the web folder files and still the app runs as it should? or the Symfony is dependent on the `vendor/`, `src/` and `app/` folders?

I don't want to send the all the Readme, CHANGELOG files in those folders and also some parts are just for development like PHPunit..

Any ideas would be appreciated as I m new to Symfony/composer workflows :)

Comment: Alternatively, you could exclude `vendor` but you would need to include `composer.lock` :-/. All others you've mentioned are mandatory, I think. Have you considered packing your app in `.phar`?

Comment: This app is like a widget where the client uploads to their folder and just includes like `widget/index.php` file and calls a function, that's it. so by distribution I mean to end user/client.